# Twilio get "type" of number. Local, Mobile, or Toll Free

Tags: twilio

Is there a way to use the Twilio API to determine if a phone number is Local, Mobile, or Toll Free?

Better yet, can this be determined at the call level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio Customer Support here.

The short answer for non Twilio numbers is no, as at time of writing Twilio does not offer a number look feature via the API.

The slightly longer answer is it depends on what country you are calling as you could create some functionality to assess the number - I can see your based in the USA, so Toll Free numbers will use 800, 888, 877, 866, 855, and 844. Unlike most other markets the USA does not distinguish between Mobile and Local numbers but other countries usually separate the two e.g. UK Mobile numbers start with +447.