# How to determine if a Twilio phone number requires a Regulatory Bundle using REST API?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

While working with Twilio's Regulatory Compliance API, I discovered that it is not possible to determine the "type" of a phone number (local, toll-free, national) after a user purchases the phone number. This property does not seem to be exposed on the `IncomingPhoneNumber` API.

This would be useful as I'd like to indicate to the user on their custom dashboard in my app (not Twilio console) that the phone number they own requires a Regulatory Compliance Bundle. However, the Regulatory Compliance API requires the following properties to list phone requirements:

- IsoCountry
- NumberType <--- I don't know how to get this value after purchasing the number?
- EndUserType

What is the suggested method for displaying to a user that a phone is missing regulatory information?

I noticed that the console API:

`https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/api/v1/inventory/PNXXXX`

DOES return the phone number type, which is then used for the following query to return compliance information:

`https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/api/v1/regulatory/regulations?isoCountry=US&numberType=local`

Would love any insight on this!

Here is a 7 year old question asking something similar. [Twilio get "type" of number. Local, Mobile, or Toll Free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745722/twilio-get-type-of-number-local-mobile-or-toll-free)

I'm trying to prevent adding phone numbers to my database so I don't have to deal with updating data in 2 locations if a user deletes/modifies a number using the Twilio API.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid there is not a generally available way to get the number type once you have bought the phone number.

There is the [global phone numbers catalog API, active numbers endpoint](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/global-catalog/api/active-numbers), but that is currently in private preview. If you have a Twilio account executive, it would be worth asking about access to this API, though I can't promise you anything.

Otherwise, I would explore storing data about the phone numbers.